# Touchpad freezing after Windows 10 update on ELAN input device

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, touchpad, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded to Windows 10 since a week, the first issue that disappointed me is this mouse freezing when I'm typing.

I googled two days, trying all solutions, nothing worked.

I have ELAN device with its tab in the Mouse property dialog

**Solution 1** : Downgraded the driver

I downgraded the driver of the mouse, after restarted nothing changed

**Solution 2** : Uninstall and Re-install (I don't recommend)

That was catastrophic for me; after restarted, the keyboard and mouse were off, I had their Big picture with their big hour ...

Auto repaire didn't work, Safe Mode same things keyboard and mouse off

I fixed this by using a USB mouse and the virtual keyboard which made me crazy before working well (finally I found that the virtual keyboard don't work well when the physic one is off)

**Solution 3** : Update to driver

I did, nothing changed

I observed that MS Word wasn't affected by that issue, I also tried to see why not Visual Studio or any other text editor ?

Perhaps someone can help me here, the solutions I shared may help other people

Comment: Similar just now: windows update -> no keyboard/touchpad -> automatic repair -> system restore -> very long wait -> still no keyboard/touchpad despite restore to a time prior to when mouse/keyboard was working! During system restore, keyboard/touchpad were clearly working, so driver is implicated. Will report answer when I find one...

Comment: Thanks for report. May be new Win10 drivers because standards or generics are more safe. You could try the manufacture one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a working solution myself:

There are two methods
1. The long (the one I did) which doesn't need computer restart
2. Short (the one I advice) which need computer restart

**Solution 1**.
Start **RegEdit**
Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPadDisplay
Set **TouchPadRejection_Display** to 1
Double-click on **ELAN Pointing Device** icon in the system tray area
Go to the third tab **Additional** then **TP Reject**
Then uncheck **Active**
Then Ok, you are done

**Solution 2**.
Start **RegEdit**
Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPad
set **DisableWhenType_Enable** to 0
Restart the PC, you are done

Now I found back my win7 mouse.

Sorry if I made any expression mistake, I am French as same as my computer

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to just try enabling the touchpad with: `Fn`+`F7`. That's what solved the problem for me after going down the drivers/registry hacks rabbit hole.

http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2008118/wont-cursor-move-acer-laptop.html

Comment: In my PC it is `fn`+`F1`, this could help others