# After update Windows 10 command prompt conflicts with ELAN touch pad driver

Tags: drivers, touchpad, scrolling

Since yesterday I am facing a strange problem. I googled for two days but found only the following issue similar to mine:
[Touchpad freezing after Windows 10 update on ELAN input device](https://superuser.com/questions/1072781/touchpad-freezing-after-windows-10-update-on-elan-input-device)
I tried both the solutions suggested here and tried many other but nothing worked.

**Real Problem**
My ELAN touchpad scroll was working fine and still works even after update until I start command prompt or file explorer. I mostly work in IDEs like netbeans, Android Studio. My ELAN touch pad scroll works fine in both of the IDEs. This means ELAN touchpad driver is working fine. But as soon as I run command prompt or open any file explorer window my scroll stops working in both of these IDEs.  Dragging two fingers on touchpad doesn't scroll up or down in these IDEs until I close command prompt or explorer windows. As soon as I close these windows my scroll starts working again in these IDEs.

This is weird. I don't think if just running a command prompt can change the behavior of currently functioning device. But to my surprise this is happening. May be someone can explain the connection and may suggest some solution.

**What I tried so far**
I have tried many solutions since yesterday.

- Updated the driver
- Downgraded the driver
- Uninstalled and re-installed the device driver
- downloaded the latest ELAN touchpad driver from my laptop
  manufacturer's site against my laptop modle Lenovo V310.
- Applied both solution from the above mentioned referenced question
- Tried changing the default mouse and touchpad settings like speed,
  sensitivity, number of lines to scroll etc. but none worked.

**System Specifications**

- OS = Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- Version = 1709
- OS Build = 16299.64
- Touchpad = ELAN Smart Pad
- Current Driver =
  https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/ce0j04af.exe
- No other mouse or pointing device installed.
- No additional driver/software installed for mouse or touch pad

**EDIT**

I dug deep into the issue and found that this is not a driver issue. Instead this is something linked with window's focus . If you have only Android Studio or netbeans opened then scroll works fine. but if you open command prompt or file explorer. then if CMD or explorer have scrollbar in it and you placed focus in your IDE and then you try to scroll then scroll event triggers but not on the focused/selected window. Instead this scroll event triggers on the back-end In-active window. 
For this I've created a video. You can view this on screencast.com .
https://www.screencast.com/t/QoVNSf46

Comment: @Ramhound yes I removed/uninstalled last 3 updates but to no avail.  I think this is something to do with windows focus. I've edited my question. Please see the edit. I've made a video of the issue and placed a link to that video.